# upload shape file in geodjango

Tags: django, geopandas, geodjango

i am Trying to upload a shape file to postgres by django and geopandas. but it return this error:

```
(psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable) relation "idx_Village_kcnT1Uu_geom" already exists
```

this is my model:

```
class ShapeFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    description = models.TextField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='user_shape_file')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and i am using this signal to upload it:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ShapeFile)
def post_save_r(instance, **kwargs):
    file = instance.file.path
    file_format = os.path.basename(file).split('.')[-1]
    file_name = os.path.basename(file).split('.')[0]
    file_path = os.path.dirname(file)
    name = instance.name
    connection = 'postgresql://postgres:1234@localhost:5432/geoapp'
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') as opened_zip:
        opened_zip.extractall(file_path)
    shape_file = glob.glob(r'{}/**/*.shp'.format(file_path), recursive=True)[0]
    gfr = gpd.read_file(shape_file)
    epsg = 4326
    engine_ = create_engine(connection)
    gfr['geom'] = gfr['geometry'].apply(lambda x: WKTElement(x.wkt, srid=epsg))
    gfr.to_sql(name, engine_, 'public', if_exists='replace', index=False,
           dtype={'geom': Geometry('Geometry', srid=epsg)})
```

but it return this error:

[image]

Comment: How many time have you run this script? I'd say it is entirely possible it worked already, at least in part, thus creating your table and every subsequent time giving you this error. Do you know SQL? You might try just looking at your database. There are lots of tools for that, including pgadmin. I've never used sqlalchemy, but have you looked at the link your error message is pointing you to? I suspect it would help you a lot.